# Extracting 'Tags' metadata from a video / image

Tags: apache-tika

In Windows OS, Images & Video files have **'Tags'** Metadata.  We can add tags to these files like 'Favouite' & 'Romantic'.    How to retrieve/extract these tag values using TIKA?

[image]

Comment: Didn't you already ask this on the Apache Tika mailing list a few days ago? What happens [when you try the things that were suggested there when you did?](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tika-dev/201604.mbox/%3CEF2DC360-55C5-4DA4-8C62-C785A7D752F8%40alfresco.com%3E)

Comment: Yep, When i run from command line, I am getting error message 'PooledTimeSeries not installed'. I could not figure out further  steps to proceed.